# bootMer output of lme4 linear mixed model: correct structure? at what level am I bootstrapping?

Tags: r, lme4, statistics-bootstrap

I have a linear mixed model that describes the relation between a continuous outcome and the interaction between a binary grouping variable (subjects are 1 out of 2 genotypes) and a time variable (5 consecutive days). Every subject has repeated measures within a day. I have 47 subjects.

Some simulated data:

```
Genotype <- as.factor(append(rep("X", 230), rep("Y", 240)))
Day <- as.factor(rep(c(1:5), 94))
Subject <- as.factor(rep(c(1:47), times=1, each=10))
jitter <- rep(jitter(0.01*c(1:47)), times=1, each=10)
Outcome <- append(rnorm(230, mean=80, sd=16), rnorm(240, mean=85, sd=18)) + jitter
Data <- data.frame(Genotype, Day, Subject, Outcome)
```

The model is coded as:

```
Lmer <- lmer(Outcome ~ Genotype*Day + (1|Subject), 
              data = Data)
```

I want to perform bootstrapping. If I calculate bootstrapping results for a specific genotype on Day 1, I use this code:

```
new_dat <- subset(Lmer, Genotype=="X" & Day=="1")
b <- bootMer(Lmer, nsim=200, 
         FUN=function(x)predict(x, newdata=new_dat, re.form=NA))
```

`b$t` now gives me a matrix of 46 columns (=N-1) with each 200 identical observations.

My goal is to bootstrap on the subject level, should I then not have only 200 bootstrapping values (thus not 46*200 values)? Am I overlooking something in my code?

Comment: what is your data?

Comment: I've added a simulated data set in the post. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: `bootMer` does *parametric* bootstrapping ...

Comment: @ Ben Bolker. Thank you for the explanation. Could you elaborate a little on the relation between "parametric bootstrapping" and the structure of `b$t` in the post above? Thanks again! (Sorry if this is supposed to be very obvious, I'm quite new to bootstrapping)